# Left Outer Join using Entity Framework and Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

```
Employee
id, name, datejoin, deptID
```

and another table that is

```
Marketing 
id, name, deptID
```

What I am trying to do is search of deptID from Employee table in Marketing to see if it exists,
if it doesn't exists want to add name and deptID from Employee table into Marketing table. 
Basically I believe it is left outer join.

I am trying to do is using lambda expressions and EF I am new to this area so was wondering how to accomplish that. I have created the entities fine need to figure out the lambda expression

```
tTlEntities sde = new tTlEntities();
sde.t_Marketing.Where(x=>x.deptID == t_Employee.deptID).
```

That is how far I went I know some outer joining is needed. Help Pleasee

Answer (score 7):

It could be done with a left outer join of employee to marketing and a check for null marketing results for the employee, or you can use not exists which in LINQ to Entities is:

```
tTlEntities sde = new tTlEntities();
var employeeQuery = sde.t_Employee.Where(
                     e=> !sde.t_Marketing.Any(m => m.deptID == e.deptID));
```

Answer (score 4):

If your `navigation property` has a `nullable foreign key id`, EF will create a `left outer join` automatically. If it's not nullable, the result would be an `inner join`. it's not necessary to write a join explicitly. just use the `Include` extension method on the navigation property which has a `nullable foreign key id`.

Comment: This does in fact work; if you want to avoid generating an FK in the db, and only wanted an ID stored, you can accomplish that by adding a manual migration when you create the relationship (add-migration) and comment out the line that makes the FK in the db. Unfortunately you still end up with a nullable column where you may've preferred an int with a default, though.

Answer (score 3):

You need `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Also the type will have to be anonymous and not employee as it needs more properties than employee.

```
var leftList = (from emp in Employees
                         join d in Departments
                         on emp.deptID equals d.Id into output
                         from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new {id = emp.Id, name = emp.name, datejoin = emp.datejoin, deptname = d.name });
```

Comment: While this might work, it doesn't use lambda expressions as requested